# Insufficient access AWS whilst using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I've been trying to access a project in AWS devicefarm using AWS CLI.
Steps taken:

- Downloaded the AWS CLI tool
- Configured my credentials according to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html using `aws configure` command
- executed `aws devicefarm list-uploads --arn myProjectArn`

and what i get is this error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListUploads operation:
> User: arn:aws:iam::replacingANumber:user/myUserName is not authorized to perform: devicefarm:ListUploads
> on resource:
> arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:replacingANumber:project:replacingALongString with an explicit deny

The docs:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting_iam.html say i'm missing permissions, but devOps team in my company says i have all the permissions.

What am I missing?

Comment: Permission denied errors are tricky to debug if you can't view your own policies. Can you ask for the policy they have put in place so you can check yourself? Also, sometimes service control policies are in place that can also block actions. Also, are you sure you are in the correct account (is the account id of the error the same as the account id in which devicefarm is configured)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either misconfigured AWS CLI or insufficient permissions.

This can be 2 things:

- Your AWS CLI is misconfigured. Make sure that when you run `aws sts get-caller-identity`, you get the same role as the one that the devops team claims to have the correct permission. Also, make sure that your default region is `us-west-2`.
- If the above is correctly setup, then it comes from the permissions defined in the IAM policy. If you are able to view the policy associated with your user/role, you can check out the [policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) to figure out which permission is missing.